# The pop up "Leave site changes may not be saved" is not getting closed even after accepting it via driver.switchTo().alert().accept()

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

We have one url in our community where if I try to edit the article and click on cancel then I get a pop up saying "Leave site changes may not be saved" when I accept this alert with code `driver.switchTo().alert().accept()` the page is redirecting to the correct page but this pop up will still remain on the page and it is blocking further execution.

I am attaching some screenshot for reference.

Pop up:

[image]

code:

[image]

=>I tried with driver.switchTo().alert().accept() method it is accepting but pop will still remain on the screen. If I try to execute same piece of code again then I'm getting error "No alert Present exception" but I can see the alert present on the web page.

=> I tried using Actions class with below code

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

but this gives exception saying "unhandled alert" are present on the web page but after accepting if I try to execute the code nothing is happening.

=> It is javascript alert and let me know if I can use JavaScript executor if yes let me know how can we use to accept this alert